# The Balloting protocol of SCP - Step 9

Tags: scp, consensus

The Paper on SCP at https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3bab/b89369eed603ce3c702f447ee6274429cda1.pdf?_ga=2.113216397.862297418.1585318681-2089854760.1525259881, describe the concrete balloting protocol as follows:
[image]

According to my understanding, when a node v is v-blocking, it unable to confirm a ballot and externalized, therefore, it runs to the next iteration of SCP (starting from step 1 again) to externalize a value eventually. This is what ensures liveness -- even when votes are stuck with quorum members having different votes. 
I have a question with step 9.

1. Why is b set to b <-  where n is the lowest counter to which
       no v-blocking set exists? (since v is v-blocking how does v find a
       ballot that is not v-blocking anyway)
2. How does this node go to step 1) again after this?

An explanation with an example would be highly appreciated (a run through the steps with an example value).
Thank you for your time.